# KSH key mapping in emacs mode: ctrl + arrow key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ksh, emacs

I'm new to KSH, have to use it at my job.  Version is:

> sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01

on RHEL.  I previously used tcsh and used its bindkey facility to give me some good command-line manipulation shortcuts.  I found the code for a "keybind" function in KSH, and used that to make home, end, and delete work the way I want:

```
keybind $'\eOH'  $'\001'
keybind $'\eOF'  $'\005'
keybind $'\e[F'  $'\005'
keybind $'\e[3~'  $'\004'
```

I'm actally not sure why I have two that correspond to "End" but I do.  In any case, the tricky part is that I want ctrl+left/right arrow to skip a word, instead of using M-f or M-b.  When I try to get the code for ctrl-left arrow, it shows:

> ^[[1;5D

but I can't seem to get this to work in the keybind command.  It seems almost like a compound keystroke due to the semicolon.  I also haven't seen this question asked before so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: After several hours of searching the internet, this is the one and only place I've found that shows how to map a Delete key that sends \e[3~ to the Emacs delete-char-forward command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KEYBD trap documented in the ksh man page is called for an incoming character sequence that begins with escape. The end of this sequence is not described, but it seems that `;` will end it.

Assuming your keybind function is as given in this [article](http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-oddthings.html), then your binding fails because the trap code is called first for `\e[1;`, then for `5` and `D`.

One solution is to change the trap code to remember the initial sequence, and use it later, as follows:

```bash
# original code from http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-oddthings.html
typeset -A Keytable
# trap 'eval "${Keytable[${.sh.edchar}]}"' KEYBD
function keybind # key action
{
    typeset key=$(print -f "%q" "$2")
    case $# in
    2)      Keytable[$1]=' .sh.edchar=${.sh.edmode}'"$key" ;;
    1)      unset Keytable[$1] ;;
    *)      print -u2 "Usage: $0 key [action]" ;;
    esac
}

# new function to handle ";" causing end of sequence
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425980/119298
function myfn {
    typeset -S state
    case "$state${.sh.edchar}" in
    $'\e[1;')   state=${.sh.edchar}
                .sh.edchar=
                return ;;
    $'\e[1;5')  state="$state${.sh.edchar}"
                .sh.edchar=
                return ;;
    $'\e[1;5'?) state=
                .sh.edchar=$'\e[1;5'"${.sh.edchar}" ;;
    esac
    eval "${Keytable[${.sh.edchar}]}"
}

trap myfn KEYBD

keybind $'\e[1;5D' $'\eb'
keybind $'\e[1;5C' $'\ef'
```